# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException

Tags: java, android-support-library

I'm new at android. I'm trying to add Google sign in feature in my app but when i add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0` in my `build.gradle` file,

i'm getting following this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: androidx/versionedparcelable/CustomVersionedParcelable.class
```

Kindly suggest solution, i spend whole day but cant get solution.

`Build.gradle` code is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.mawai.smartlearn"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In version 17.0.0 and above, you need to use AndroidX, so you have **2 options**:

> 1) Downgrade **com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth** to older version
>
> 2) Add/Migrate AndroidX to your app (Recommended)
>
> **Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for migration**